# How to debug SIGSEGV with gdb

Tags: c++, linux, debugging, segmentation-fault, gdb

I ran into a segmentation fault error while running a Linux application and I am debugging.

There are limitations because I am new to gdb and unfamiliar with sementation debugging.

The only information I can get is the following log.

```
GNU gdb (GDB) 8.2
Copyright (C) 2018 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
Type "show copying" and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "arm-linux-gnueabi".
Type "show configuration" for configuration details.
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:
    <http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/>.

For help, type "help".
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word"...
Reading symbols from /usr/bin/sementation_fault_test...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
[New LWP 9660]

warning: Unable to find libthread_db matching inferior's thread library, thread debugging will not be available.

warning: Unable to find libthread_db matching inferior's thread library, thread debugging will not be available.
Core was generated by `sementation_fault_test'.
Program terminated with signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
#0  0xc0101fd0 in ?? ()
(gdb) bt
#0  0xc0101fd0 in ?? ()
#1  0x00072484 in Test::segmentationFaultTest() ()
Backtrace stopped: previous frame inner to this frame (corrupt stack?)
```

1. How can I get information about ?? in #0 ?? () ?
2. Is the address address for virtual memory? It's different every time, so why is it different? Is there any way to find out what it is?
3. let me know in whatever way I can approach the issue further.

Comment: You don't seem to have compiled the program with debugging symbols. Try compiling with `-g` or preferably `-ggdb3` and see if you get better information when debugging.

Answer (score 2):

A segmentation fault is merely a highly technical term for "the program's memory is in unknown state, anywhere between some random bytes getting corrupted due to a wild pointer dereference, a buffer overrun, or something along those lines; and the program's entire memory getting replaced by an output of a cryptographic random number generator".

`gdb` can only show you the current of the process. It cannot do anything about unreadable, binary junk. It cannot peer into the past and see what was in the process's memory before it gave up the ghost, crashed, and burned.

It is not unusual to see gdb unable to interpret one or more stack frames, and tell you "sorry, no soup for you". This happens for any number of reasons: stack frame corruption, the function call is inside a shared library that has no debug symbols, or other reasons.

Here, `gdb` did seem to figure out that the stack frame is two calls deep from somewhere in `Test::segmentationFaultTest()`. That's probably true, but it may not be.

There is no paint-by-numbers, cookie-cutter, step-by-step procedure to investigate and debug every possible crash, using gdb. Each situation is unique. Knowing how to effectively use `gdb` comes from experience. The more you continue to use `gdb` the more you will understand what's going on, how it works, how to use it, and how to use it effectively. This process, and acquiring debugging skills take time. Be patient. Congratulate yourself on being aware that `gdb` actually exists, which is a lot more knowledge, in itself, than a good majority of similar questions here. So, you're already ahead in that game.

Here, I would use the `up` command to move up the stack frame, twice, and see where exactly the fatal function call occurred in `Test::segmentationFaultTest`, and see what's going on there. Various `gdb` commands will let you examine what's in all the variables, and hopefully you will be able to extract more useful information to go on, from that.

If the core dump is determined to be completely useless, the next step is to start the program directly in the debugger, and set a breakpoint somewhere in the code where you think the program is still functioning normally, then run it. If your breakpoint gets hit, you can satisfy yourself by using gdb to examine the various variables, and determine whether everything is good, so far, or something's already off the rails.

Based on that conclusion you can decide where to set the next breakpoint, ahead in the code, or back up and set a new breakpoint earlier, and rerun the program from the beginning. In this fashion, incrementally, you will zero in on when things start to go sideways, and hopefully figure out why.

As far as the address of the crash being different: again, there can be many reasons for that. Anywhere from the crash caused by some random factor, which is different every time; to your operating system employing virtual address space randomization as a security measure.